# Put/Post errors while trying to access it from through python. "Bad Request. The JSON payload should be inside a root property called

Tags: python, post, put, 400-bad-request

I am trying to post/put to Sheety via Python:

```py
SHEETY_URL = "https://api.sheety.co/gfhgfhjfdghjgfjf/flightDeals/prices/5"

header = {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
}
params_sheety = {
    "price": {
        "iataCode": "PLN"
    }
}
response_sheety = requests.put(url=SHEETY_URL, params=params_sheety, headers=header)
print(response_sheety)
print(response_sheety.json())
```

=======================================================

Getting Bad request Error:

> <Response [400]> {'errors': [{'detail': "Bad Request. The JSON payload
> should be inside a root property called 'price'. Check
> https://sheety.co/docs for more details."}]}

The same request works fine with Postman.

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `params=params_sheety`, the parameters are not sent as json.

Use `json=params_sheety` to send them as json.

This also sets the content-type header to json automatically, so you don't need `headers=header`.

Comment: Then I get <Response [524]>

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\shromivchuk\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: 524 appears to be a timeout.  Perhaps this is a firewall issue?  Is this code running on the same computer where you run postman?

Comment: the same computer

Comment: It works now, passing it as json solved the issue, I just messed up with the url thats why it had returned the 524